# Will the Macbook Air (Mid 2012) support dual monitors?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dual-screen

Can I hook up two external monitors (with a HDMI interface) to a MacBook Air 2012?

I don't want to use the MacBook Air monitor when the two monitors are used.

Answer (score 5):

You can hook up two external monitors by using the thunderbolt port that support daisy chaining. You connect the the first screen with your Macbook air and connect the second screen with the first screen.

According to the following [KB-article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US#minimul) the following models support up to 2 displays through one thunderbolt port.

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012) and later
- MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) and later
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch and 17-inch, Early 2011) and later
- MacBook Air (Mid 2012) and later
- iMac (Late 2012)
- iMac (Mid 2011)
- Mac Mini (Late 2012)
- Mac Mini (Mid 2011), 2.5 GHz

It's not possible to connect 2 monitors simultaneously through one hdmi port.

[image: twomonitorsetup]

[Arstechnica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/06/new-macbooks-can-manage-many-many-monitors/) also has an article about the support of multiple external monitors through one thunderbolt port. Apparently the older Macbook airs only support one external screen due to limitations in the thunderbolt host controller.

Comment: It's confusing to read "Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on **an** external display" on [the product page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP670?locale=en_US). The page mentions dual DVI adapters, but still, it does not say that it actually supports two monitors with it.