# Is it possible to connect a second external monitor to Macbook Air Mid 2013?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, dvi

I have one external monitor connected to Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter on MacBook Air Mid 2003. Now I have a spare monitor with DVI, HDMI and VGA input amd I'd like to add that as a second external display. Is it possible to connect another external monitor to a USB to HDMI adapter? I guess that would be the cheapest option if it worked? Then there's also Mini DisPlayPort with dual-link DVI. Is that supported by Air Mid 2013?

This is all very confusing and different sites seem to give different and conflicting info.

Comment: It will support one external monitor.  The Intel chip can *technically* support two monitors, but it requires MST which isn’t supported by macOS. If you were running Windows on the Air, then it would support two.

Comment: But according to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98972/will-the-macbook-air-mid-2012-support-dual-monitors) even an older Macbook Air supports two external monitors?